# meromorphic at $\infty$ is a polynomial?

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces

I do not understand the statement why $p$ will be polynomial in the following statement:

"The function $p:\hat{\mathbb C}\rightarrow\hat{\mathbb C}$ defined by $p(z)=f(z)q(z)$ has the removable singularities at the poles of $f$ in $\mathbb C$, so it is entire, this it has power series representation on all $\mathbb C$, also $p$ is meromorphic at $\infty$ as both $f$ and $q$ are.this forces $p$ to be a polynomial.Since, $f=\frac pq$"
$$ q(z)=\prod_{j=1}^{n}(z-z_j)^{e_j}$$

Comment: What are $f(Z)$ and $q(z)$?

Comment: You really should answer Makoto Kato's question, in order to make your question comprehensible.  But also, notice that \Pi_{j=1}^n gives you $\displaystyle\Pi_{j=1}^n$, whereas \prod_{j=1}^n gives you $\displaystyle\prod_{j=1}^n$.  The subscripts are positioned differently when they're in display style, and I think there are also differences when they're in inline style.  The latter form is standard.  Similar comments apply to \Sigma versus \sum.

Comment: $F(z)$ is a meromorphic function in extended plane, which has poles at $z_1,\dots z_n$ with multiplicity $e_1,\dots, e_n$

Answer (score 3):

What does it mean to have a pole at $\infty$? This means that the function has a pole when written in terms of the coordinate $w=\frac1z$ .

Comment: Or that the function approaches $\infty$ as the argument approaches $\infty$.

Comment: @Michael: Yes, that is a good way to put it. So the function does not go crazy.